# Datagridview and database

Tags: c#, postgresql, datagridview

I have created a datagridview and fill it with data from postgresql database

```
string connString = "Server=" + HOST + ";Port=" + PORT + "; User Id=" + USER + ";Password=" + PASSWORD + ";Database=" + DATABASE + "";
            string query = "SELECT c.id as Numéro,nom_beneficier,date_saisie,cat.designation,cat.taux,montant_brut,montant_rs,net_rs " 
                           +"From crs_certificat c,crs_beneficier b,crs_categorie_taux cat "
                           +"WHERE c.id_beneficier=b.id AND c.categorie=cat.id ORDER BY Numéro DESC";
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
            try
            {
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                listCertificat.DataSource = dt;

            }catch(Exception ex){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

but the columns names datagridview's header are the same of the query !! 
how can I can change them and display my owen names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your own names for columns in the query also

see this example

```
 select 1 "My_Column",'a_string_value'::varchar "My_Second_Column"
```

will return

```
My_Column     My_Second_Column
Integer       character varying
-------------------------------------
       1      a_string_value
```

you can give your desired column name in select query, so that your select query should be like this:

```
SELECT c.id  "Numéro",
       nom_beneficier "your_column_name" ,
       date_saisie "your_column_name",
       cat.designation "your_column_name",
       cat.taux,montant_brut "your_column_name",
       montant_rs "your_column_name",
       net_rs "your_column_name"
From crs_certificat c,crs_beneficier b,crs_categorie_taux cat 
WHERE c.id_beneficier=b.id AND c.categorie=cat.id ORDER BY  "Numéro" DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

assigning the Header text of the gridview. Go to Properties of the `GridView-->Columns-->Add the column` and set the `DataBound` to the DB `Column name` and `Header Text` Property.

Or if you want to set your header programmatically then use following code:-

```
 GridView_Id.Columns[0].HeaderText = "HeaderName";
 //This will change the GridView’s first column to “HeaderName
```

else

```
protected void grdSearchResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "your header name";
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I did that but when I get the data from database the header text get the text of columns in the query.

Comment: in gridview, Edit columns and set header text what you want to display to every field  and set datafield property under data (Table column name)